# Facebook SDK for JavaScript Share dialog not working for Facebook and Instagram URL

Tags: facebook, fbsdksharedialog

My code:

```
function LaunchFeedDialog(){
    FB.ui({
  method: 'share',
  href: 'https://www.facebook.com/KidsPublicSpeaking',
  app_id: '1665615247095212',
}, function(response){});
}
```

It shows error upon sharing for any Facebook/Instagram URL:

[image]

But it's working fine if I change the "href" to non Facebook/Instagram URL.
Need advice on this. Thanks.